# Stopping AVAudioPlayer at a certain time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play a segment of a sound clip. How would I stop the AVAudioPlayer at a certain time?

I have a function that when called from a slider value, will set the playtime to a given place. (songStart and SongEnd are simply a percentage of the song)
What function could I build to stop it at a certain point?

```
    func setSongConstraints(songStart: Double, songEnd: Double){
         audioPlayer.currentTime = audioPlayer.duration * songStart
    }
```

I know an option would be to set a wait timer or something, and then call stop after that amount of time.

However, I'd like the function to allow for the end point of the song to be changed after the song starts. The wait timer wouldn't work in this instance, as it would need to be changed after it had started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **could** use a [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) to check the `currentTime` property of your [`AVAudioPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime) object.

**For Example**

Start the timer when you start playing the audio. Adjusting the check interval `0.1` based on the level of accuracy required.

```
var timer:Timer!

timer = Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
    0.1, 
    target: self, 
    selector: "checkTime",
    userInfo: nil, 
    repeats: true
)
```

Then create the function that the timer runs every `0.1` second to check the audio players current time against your own value where `END_TIME` could be updated or replaced by your `songEnd` logic.

```
let END_TIME = 10.0

func checkTime() {
    if self.audioPlayer.currentTime >= END_TIME {
        self.audioPlayer.stop()
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems unnecessarily expensive and coarse... the audio would only stop on one-second boundaries, and you have to poll every second.  My solution below resets the timer so that it only has to fire once, then kill the audio.

Comment: @RehcsifMit cool, can you show some code to help demonstrate it?

Comment: I agree with the comments above. This method is expensive with regard to overhead and doesn't really help when precision is required.

Comment: I've edited the answer to intimate that this is just one option. I'd love to see some more options/answers in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wait timer.  If the user resets the endpoint of the song, just reset the timer to to the new delta of  - .  You can do that by either killing the existing timer and spawning a new one, or changing the fireDate of the existing timer.  Be sure to handle the condition where the new endpoint is earlier than the currentTime... then you should just call stop and kill the existing timer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you do not want to do a wait timer, but you could always just keep track of how much time has lapsed and reset the timer when new data is available. Or I guess poll NSDate in some kind of loop.

Comment: say you want to pause in 5 seconds,

you check if nsdate is passed this 5 second mark, then stop;

e.g.
`let myDate = NSDate()
while(1==1){if(myDate.timeLapseSinceNow < -5){end song}}`

This is not tested code, just an idea that is outside of the timer

Comment: You would still need something to fire a check every second, seems overkill to involve a date object to just wait 5 seconds.

Comment: you would be checking in the runloop, or the update loop, nothing would fire.  It is an alternative to using timers., it is not how I would do it lol